# Combine Scala Future[Seq[X]] with Seq[Future[Y]] to produce Future[(X,Seq[Y])]

Tags: scala, future

I have below relationship in my entity classes,
`customer -> * Invoice`
now I have to implement a method which returns customers with their invoices

```
type CustomerWithInvoices = (Custimer,Seq[Invoice])

  def findCustomerWitnInvoices:Future[Seq[CustomerWithInvoices]] = {
    for{
      customers <- findCustomers
      eventualInvoices: Seq[Future[Seq[Invoice]]] = customers.map(customer => findInvoicesByCustomer(customer))

    } yield ???
  }
```

using existing repository methods as below

```
def findCustomers:Future[Seq[Customers]] = {...}

def findInvoicesByCustomer(customer:Customer):Future[Seq[Invoice]] = {...}
```

I try to use `for` expression as above but I can't figure the proper way to do it, as I'm fairly new to Scala, highly appreciate any help..

Comment: You cannot map it to `Future[(Customer, Seq[Invoice])]`, because there are multiple customers and multiple invoices per customer. You probably want `Future[Seq[(Customer, Seq[Invoice])]]` (or `Future[Seq[CustomerWithInvoices]]` with the alias).

Comment: sorry my bad @marstran you are correct, I have mistype the signature

Comment: i think that you need to have an arrow in the second line of the for-comp, otherwise you'll stack futures and end up with horrific type `Future[Future[Blabla]]`

Comment: Maybe: `findCustomers.flatMap { customers => Future.traverse(customers)(customer => findInvoicesByCustomer(customer).map(invoices => (customer -> invoices)) ) }`. - **for-comprehensions** aren't really good when you mix two different types.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 0):

i would use `Future.sequence`, the simplified method signature is 
`sequence takes M[Future[A]] and returns Future[M[A]]`
That is what we need to solve your problem, here's the code i would write:

```
val eventualCustomersWithInvoices: Future[Seq[(Customer, Seq[Invoice])]] = for {
      customers <- findCustomers()
      eventualInvoices <- Future.sequence(customers.map(customer => findInvoicesByCustomer(customer)))

    } yield eventualInvoices
```

note that the type of `eventualInvoices` is `Future[Seq[(Customer, Seq[Invoice])]]` hence  `Future[Seq[CustomerWithInvoices]]`